# Compiling QT Include path detected by configure but not found by nmake

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, qt5, nmake

iam trying to built QT5 static together with mysql support on Win8.1 and Visual Studio Compiler 2010.

Tried to follow the upstream Readme, thats my build command (executed as administrator within the VS terminal):

```
configure -static -qt-sql-mysql -prefix %CD%\qtbase -opensource -nomake tests -release 
-nomake examples -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\include" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"
-l "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\lib\opt"
-l "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers"
-l "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\" -mp
```

The result is this, it seems configure found the path correctly:

```
Sql Drivers:
    ODBC....................no
    MySQL...................yes
    OCI.....................no
    PostgreSQL..............no
    TDS.....................no
    DB2.....................no
    SQLite..................yes (qt)
    SQLite2.................no
    InterBase...............no

Sources are in..............C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase
Build is done in............C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase
Install prefix..............C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase
Headers installed to........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\include
Libraries installed to......C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\lib
Arch-dep. data to...........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase
Plugins installed to........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\plugins
Library execs installed to..C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\bin
QML1 imports installed to...C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\imports
QML2 imports installed to...C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\qml
Binaries installed to.......C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\bin
Arch-indep. data to.........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase
Docs installed to...........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\doc
Translations installed to...C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\translations
Examples installed to.......C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\examples
Tests installed to..........C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\tests
Include paths...............C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1
.3\include C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include
Additional libraries........-lC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1
.1.3\lib\opt -lC:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -lC:\Program
Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib"
WARNING: Using static linking will disable the use of plugins.
     Make sure you compile ALL needed modules into the library.

Generating Makefiles...
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/qmodule.pri:13: Missing closing " quote


Qt is now configured for building. Just run nmake.
To reconfigure, run nmake confclean and configure.
```

Now the problem, iam only running

```
nmake
```

The result

```
          cl -c -FIqt_pch.h -Yuqt_pch.h -Fp.pch\release\Qt5Sql_pch.pch -nologo -Zm
   200 -Zc:wchar_t -arch:SSE2 -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQ
   T_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_SQL_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNIN
   GS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_C
   OMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_B
   EFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -DS
   QLITE_OMIT_COMPLETE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLI
   TE_ENABLE_RTREE -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\..\include"
    -I"..\..\include\QtSql" -I"..\..\include\QtSql\5.3.2" -I"..\..\include\QtSql\5.
   3.2\QtSql" -I"tmp" -I"..\3rdparty\sqlite" -I"..\..\include\QtCore\5.3.2" -I"..\.
   .\include\QtCore\5.3.2\QtCore" -I"..\..\include\QtCore" -I".moc\release" -I"..\.
   .\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\kili\AppData\Local\Temp\nm4
   574.tmp
   qsqldatabase.cpp
   c:\qt\qt5.3.2\5.3\src\qtbase\src\sql\kernel\../drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql_p.h(63)
   : fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "mysql.h": No s
   uch file or directory
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
   \VC\BIN\cl.EXE"": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
   \VC\BIN\nmake.exe"": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
   Stop.
```

mysql.h isnt found but it is in the include with was correctly found by configure:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include>dir
    Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
    Volumeseriennummer: 5E70-A76B

    Verzeichnis von C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include

   20.06.2014  17:35    <DIR>          .
   20.06.2014  17:35    <DIR>          ..
   11.06.2014  05:10             3.654 big_endian.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.555 byte_order_generic.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.504 byte_order_generic_x86.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             5.193 decimal.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             4.297 errmsg.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             7.078 keycache.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             3.134 little_endian.h
   20.06.2014  17:35    <DIR>          mysql
   11.06.2014  05:10            29.219 mysql.h
   11.06.2014  06:19            98.278 mysqld_ername.h
   11.06.2014  06:19            36.517 mysqld_error.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            24.846 mysql_com.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.313 mysql_com_server.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.142 mysql_embed.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.172 mysql_time.h
   11.06.2014  06:19               989 mysql_version.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.009 my_alloc.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             5.488 my_byteorder.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             3.678 my_compiler.h
   11.06.2014  06:18            12.311 my_config.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             8.281 my_dbug.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.940 my_dir.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             6.163 my_getopt.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            25.504 my_global.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.506 my_list.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.978 my_net.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            19.960 my_pthread.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            40.760 my_sys.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.821 my_xml.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            34.935 m_ctype.h
   11.06.2014  05:10            11.037 m_string.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             7.098 sql_common.h
   11.06.2014  06:19            13.677 sql_state.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.678 sslopt-case.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.511 sslopt-longopts.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             1.968 sslopt-vars.h
   11.06.2014  05:10             2.282 typelib.h
          36 Datei(en),        430.476 Bytes
           3 Verzeichnis(se), 109.641.277.440 Bytes frei
```

Can somebody tell me what iam doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you figured it out?

Comment: Sorry, did not investigated further in this case and made a dynamic build.

Comment: That's OK, I got it.